# Request to delete answer on WDL question

Tags: support

Could the mods kindly look at the 'answer' to:
[Pulling Multiple Files via rsync with WDL](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19346/pulling-multiple-files-via-rsync-with-wdl)

Its been there 17 hours. The username is also an issue. I've no links to WDL, but the post is intentional slander.

Comment: WDL is workflow description language, started by Broad Institute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted it now. Thanks for flagging it.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response @DevonRyan